# How do I add a constant and literal in an annotation?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to add a constant and literal in an annotation, but end up getting an "annotation argument needs to be a constant" error. I set up some example code that also produces the same error.

### HelloWorld.scala

```
package test

@TestAnnotation(Constants.test + ", world!")
object HelloWorld {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("Hello, world!")
  }
}
```

### Constants.scala

```
package test

object Constants {
  final val test = "Hello"
}
```

### TestAnnotation.java

```
package test;

@interface TestAnnotation {
    String value();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking at http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/9363 and expecting to tell you that you needed `static` and/or `final` (which you already have) on your `Constants.test`, but i ran your code and it **works** under 2.10.4

```
$ sbt run
[info] Compiling 2 Scala sources and 1 Java source to .../so22717836annotation/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[info] Running HelloWorld 
Hello, world!
```

here's the code:

```
$ for i in `echo build.sbt; find src/main -type f`; do \
    echo '###' $i '###'; echo; perl -pe 's/^/    /' $i; echo; done
```

#### build.sbt

```
name := "so22717836"

version := "0.0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"
```

#### src/main/java/test/TestAnnotation.java

```
package test;

public @interface TestAnnotation {
    String value();
}
```

#### src/main/scala/HelloWorld.scala

```
import test._

@TestAnnotation(Constants.test + ", world!")
object HelloWorld {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("Hello, world!")
  }
}
```

#### src/main/scala/Constants.scala

```
object Constants {
  final val test = "Hello"
}
```

Comment: Huh... Eclipse was giving me an error... I'm just going to switch back to Java, but thanks for the help!