# static final in scala annotation

Tags: java, scala, annotations, scala-java-interop

I have a java class with constants:

```java
public abstract class TestGroup {
    public static final String UNIT = "unit";
    ...
}
```

in java I can use it in an annotation:

```java
@Test(groups=TestGroup.UNIT)
public class Unit1Test {...}
```

but when I do it in Scala (2.10.4):

```scala
@Test(groups=Array(TestGroup.UNIT))
class Unit2Test{...}
```

I get this compilation error:

```
 error: annotation argument needs to be a constant; found: TestGroup.UNIT
 [ERROR] @Test(groups=Array(TestGroup.UNIT))
 [ERROR]                              ^
```

how can I use annotations with constants in Scala with cross-compilation?

Note: the previous question [How do I add a constant and literal in an annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22717836/how-do-i-add-a-constant-and-literal-in-an-annotation) doesn't help, as it shows Scala constants in Scala code. I want to use Java constants from Scala code.

Comment: See my answer to [Using scala constants in constant expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23703966/651140)

Comment: nope, that's different problem. i updated the question, plz unlock

Comment: Did anyone bother to look at the issue I linked to? Maybe the OP could specify how the sources are compiled.

Comment: yes it looks like that problem but sequential compilation is not an option. so if question is reopened maybe i get some workarounds

Comment: My point was that this is not a duplicate, @ajozwik, let alone an exact one. The answer explained your problem, but obviously went unloved.

Comment: Question is not duplicated. Remove abstract and try again. For scala 2.11.1 it is possible.`import org.testng.annotations.Test
class MyTest {
  @Test(groups = Array(java.util.jar.JarFile.MANIFEST_NAME))
  def annTest{
    assert(1 == 1)
  }
}`

Comment: still no answer yet !?, for scala 2.11.7 it is not working !!